# double only numeric values of an object in typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

How to get rid of the error? `The left-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any', 'number', 'bigint' or an enum type.` See the following code.

```js
function doubleNumericValuesOfObj<TType extends {}>(obj: TType){
    for(const key in obj){
        if(typeof obj[key] === 'number'){
            //  this is the type error:  The left-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any', 'number', 'bigint' or an enum type.
            obj[key] *= 2;
        }
    }
}
```